# node.js console - What is `undefined` in node console?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm novice in javascript. My knowlegde in scripting languages is python, and we know that it use modules for specific task. In any python console, we can use

```
import numpy as np
```

But it do not return anything in the console. So if i use the "same" thing in a node console i get this

```
var module = require('module')
undefined
```

So, i'm wondering what mean that `undefined` return from node console.

Comment: `var module; module = require('module')` has other behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the return value from declaring a variable with `var`. Since it doesn't return anything, you get `undefined`. The assignment itself does however return the right-hand-side value, so chaining assignments is possible.

Answer (score 2):

undefined means that the expression do not have a return.

Answer (score 1):

Every command in node returns undefined unless you tell it to return something else. It won't affect anything your program, it is just the default return statement.